# Gotta equivalents

Tags: expressions

I have done a **bad** classification of the **oral** use of these expressions. Been the most used 1 and the less 5.

What is the most used in spoken American English?

1. I gotta
2. I got to
3. I've gotta
4. I've got to
5. I have to
6. I have got to

Comment: They're all the same. The difference between them only exists in written English. In spoken English people choose among various shades of the morphemes, instant by instant. There is no sharp distinction between pronunciations; only between spellings.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be rephrased as "Which shades of morphemes are most commonly chosen?" Pronunciation is on-topic.

Comment: One more comment: you omitted *I hafta* from your list.

Comment: One could go on with eye spellings all day. They don't refer to anything in language, only in the spelling habits of the writers.

Comment: @JohnLawler The question **is** about pronunciation. *How* something is said has to be represented somehow; IPA is best, but it's a representation of pronunication which is attempted in this question, in order to support "Which pronunciation is most commonly used?"

Comment: There are **thousands** of possible pronunciations of that modal complex, and not just six or seven. Asking "Which pronunciation is most commonly used?" when presenting misspelled examples instead of phonetic representations is silly. Spose we misspelled a few more and added them to the list -- how would anybody know what sounds they were sposta be referring to? It's just impossible to discuss pronunciation in a silent medium without some basic knowledge of phonetics.

Comment: If the list includes *have to* and *have got to*, then it perhaps should include others as well: *need to*, *must*,...

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "I have got to" is often used with emphasis on 'got' to express either greater desire, or possibly sarcasm.

For example, "I love your new iPhone. I have GOT to get one."

Versus: "The new iPhone sucks. I have GOT to get one."

Comment: This is true of many idioms, and stress forms yet another dimension of variation in speech, not capturable in writing.